# Android animation to rotate a view and freeze it after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am new to [Android Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) and want to do a basic animation

1. Rotate a view by 180deg

   ```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <rotate
       android:fromDegrees="0"
       android:toDegrees="180"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="300"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:fillEnabled="true"
        />
   ```

but the problem is after animation is done the view returns to its original position 
i want the view to be 180deg rotated after animation is done

I also added a **AnimationListener** with **onAnimationEnd** to do it but it gives some glitch

Comment: OnAnimationEnd set `rotation` of your view.

Comment: @Yugesh i tried with onAnimationEnd to rotation the view but for fraction of a second it shows the view in original position and the changes the applied rotation

Comment: can you help me with the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hey use this ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="180" />

 </set>
```